# Can I suppress newlines after each template tag with Django's template engine?

Tags: django, django-templates

In Rails ERB, you can suppress newlines by adding a trailing hyphen to tags:

```
<ul>
  <% for @item in @items -%>
    <li><%= @item %></li>
  <% end -%>
</ul>
```

becomes:

```
<ul>
    <li>apple</li>
    <li>banana</li>
    <li>cacao</li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to do this in Django? (Disclosure: I'm generating a csv file with Django)

Edit: Clarified that the newlines I'm hunting down are the ones left behind after the template *tags*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest I've found to what you're looking for (I'm looking for the same thing) is talk about a future patch, here: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/2594.

Unfortunately, it looks like there's not much you can do until they merge that patch in.

Comment: They are never going to merge that patch in. The bug report has been closed with a message essentially saying that Django's template engine won't see new features and that the plan is to have Jinja be the engine of choice for Django.

Answer (score 3):

```
{% spaceless %}
<ul>
    <li>apple</li>
    <li>banana</li>
    <li>cacao</li>
</ul>
{% endspaceless %}
```

I am not aware about any way to discard template tags lines. I'd vote for opening bug report.

Comment: This removes all newlines, it doesn't supress newlines from lines containing only template tags.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
<ul>
{% for obj in list %}
    <li>{{ obj|linebreaksbr|striptags }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Or this, which also strips whitespaces/tabs/etc, between HTML tags:

```
{{ spaceless }}
<ul>
{% for obj in list %}
    <li>{{ obj }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{{ endspaceless }}
```

Comment: Your second example removes all newlines, not just those caused by having template tags on their own lines. Your first example just strips newlines if obj has them....not exactly what the OP was asking for.

Answer (score 1):

It is 2016 now, and I think this issue is still present.
In this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQjmz9wCjLA
at around 1:45 a unittest of a template shows that there is a trailing newline on the end of the  tag.

Comment: It is now 2017, and still no reasonable solution to this!

Comment: Jinja2 has a solution for this : https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#whitespace-control

Answer (score 0):

When you write a template, you could open the ul hardcoded in the template and looping trought items en returning there value with the  in it.

As far as i know there isn't a default function for that.