# Suppress line breaks after each templatetag in django

Tags: django, django-templates, templatetags

I searched around, but didn't find a nice way to solve this issue so far, so hoping you can help.
I am using django template language for all my plaintext emails and it is very inconvenient that each templatetag renders with an additional line break. While it allows me to have nicely formatted templates the rendered text contains multiple newlines which I am not being able to control unless I make my template ugly by removing the new lines after the templatetags. Please note that I am using it for text rendering, and any "spaceless" will not work here.

Example:

```
email1.txt

{%load i18n%}
{%with name=something.somethingelse.name%}
Hello {{name}},
{%endwith%}

Hope you are well.
```

`render_to_string("email1.txt",context)`

The output will be:

```
<line break>
<line break>
Hello Someone,
<line break>
<line break>
Hope you are well.
```

My last resort is to manually read the templates into string, do a regex stripping of new lines before passing it to rendering so I enjoy the both worlds, but I wonder if someone has a better idea.

```
with open('email1.txt') as fd:
    eml1 = fd.read()
eml1 = re.sub(r'%}[ \t]*\n', '%}', eml1)
Template(eml1).render(Context(context))
```

Comment: Regex is already the easiest method, or you need to extend method for the template engine.

Comment: Another solution would be to use Jinja2: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#whitespace-control

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I suppress newlines after each template tag with Django's template engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606149/can-i-suppress-newlines-after-each-template-tag-with-djangos-template-engine)

Comment: That ticket asks about HTML rendering and spaceless is offered as a solution, which is not the case for me as outlined above.

Comment: I edited the question to show my "last resort" code. If anyone has a cleaner way, please post it as a solution and I will accept.